# ImageMagick Command Line Photo Editing

Tags: imagemagick

I have the following lightroom presets that I am trying to get as close to with CLI for ImageMagick7.

Highlights -20
Temp 7500
Tint +10
Sharpening 25
NoiseReduction 5
Color Noise Reduction 5

Comment: There is no way to know what Adobe has coded for the functions for those presets. So the only way would be trial and error with similar ImageMagick operations.

Comment: If have lightroom, you can get something to do the highlights, temperature and tinting using ImageMagick HALD 3D lookup. Create the HALD image in ImageMagick, move it Lightroom. Apply those presets to it and save uncompressed. Then bring that modified HALD image back to ImageMagick an use it to apply to any other image using -hald-clut. You cannot do sharpening or noise reduction or any spatially varying operation using the HALD. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#hald-clut